# how to set selected value of combo box in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have two combo box ( say cbo_zone & cbo_floor ) which are having table as the data source

```
private void load_cbo_zone() 
    { 
        clz_Common_References ccr = new clz_Common_References ();
        DataTable dt_zone = ccr.get_zone_detail();
        cbo_zone.DataSource = dt_zone;
        cbo_zone.ValueMember = "ID";
        cbo_zone.DisplayMember = "zone";
        cbo_zone.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

`

```
    private void load_cbo_floor()
    {
        int ID_zone_ref = Convert.ToInt16(cbo_zone.SelectedValue);
        clz_Common_References ccr = new clz_Common_References();
        DataTable dt_flr = ccr.get_floor_data_fr_Ref_IDZone(ID_zone_ref);
        cbo_floor.DataSource = dt_flr;
        cbo_floor.DisplayMember = "Floor";
        cbo_floor.ValueMember = "ID";
        cbo_floor.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

` . I wrote the code to update the cbo_floor as following .

```
private void cbo_zone_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        load_cbo_floor();
    }
```

Now I need to update the cbo_zone & cbo_floor when I click a data row of datagridview .

```
int ref_area_id, ref_floor_id, ref_zone_id;

        int.TryParse(dt_issued_mat.Rows[0][11].ToString(), out ref_area_id);
        DataTable dt_area_detail = ccr.get_area_data_fr_area_id(ref_area_id);
        int.TryParse(dt_area_detail.Rows[0][2].ToString(), out ref_floor_id);
        DataTable dt_floor_detail = ccr.get_floor_data_fr_floor_id(ref_floor_id);
        int.TryParse(dt_floor_detail.Rows[0][2].ToString(), out ref_zone_id);
        DataTable dt_zone_detail = ccr.get_zone_data_fr_zone_id(ref_zone_id);
```

after that using

```
cbo_zone.Text  = dt_zone_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString();
cbo_floor.Text  = dt_floor_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

I was able to display the values on the combo boxes but once I tried to get the cbo_floor.SelectedValue code doesn't work .

Then I was able to get the relevant SelectedIndex by using ,

```
int index = cbo_zone.FindString(dt_zone_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString());
        cbo_zone.SelectedIndex  = index ;
```

still the combo box shows nothing & "cbo_zone.SelectedValue"  doesn't
show a value.my target is to get the cbo_floor.SelectedValue .
Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cbo_zone.Text  = dt_zone_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString();
cbo_floor.Text  = dt_floor_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString();`

Use

```
cbo_zone.Items.Add( dt_zone_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```

`cbo_floor.Items.Add ( dt_floor_detail.Rows[0][1].ToString());`

Comment: since combo boxes has data source above command an't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

First working with indexes is not a good idea. You have the value, use them. Using the index will cause you trouble.

```
cbo_zone.SelectedValue = myValue.ToString();//find the value from your data
```

Secondly for selecting the floor, you need to fill it with the relevant values first, since it already has the data for the last selection.

```
  load_cbo_floor();
  cbo_floor.SelectedValue = myValue.ToString();//find the value from your data
```